# Initialize array with extra element using a macro

Tags: c++, arrays, macros, initialization, c-preprocessor

I am initializing an array in two different ways depending a macro:

```
# if feature_enabled
const int v[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
#else
const int v[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
#endif
```

The problem is that the data in the assignment is actually large matrices, and for various reasons it's not a good solution to just copy the data with a minor modification (just one more element at the beginning of the array.)

I was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing that I did here, without essentially duplicating the last n-1 elements.

Comment: Do you know that the array size does not match the number of elements in the initializer list?

Comment: @mch fixed it now, it was just something I typed up for the question.

Comment: @C.E. "and for various reasons it's not a good solution to just copy the data with a minor modification" - Could you give us a reference for that, what is your worry about?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica Why, in general, is duplicating code bad? That's a rather broad topic. Luckily, I got my answer anyway.

Comment: @C.E. You do not need to make an over-detailed explanation, it were just be fine if you could give a reference at least to what you are pointing to and which is the base of that question. So, people who aren´t confirmed with these things can understand the purpose of that question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't specify the size on the array but let it be auto-deduced, you can just add the 0 in the front conditionally:

```
const int v[] = {
# if feature_enabled
  0,
#endif
  1, 2, 3, 4
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to keep the array size, then:

```
# if feature_enabled
const int v[4] = {
#else
const int v[5] = {0,
#endif
  1, 2, 3, 4
};
```